# Formula / algorithm to calculate/convert Excel column width to Word table column width

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am looking for at formula which can convert Excel columns width to Word table width. 
Example: Create a simple table in excel, change the width of the columns. Finally copy / paste it to a MS Word document.

Upon examination the two files it shows.

MS Excel:

```
<x:cols>
    <x:col min="1" max="1" width="3.77734375" customWidth="1" />
    <x:col min="2" max="2" width="10.21875" customWidth="1" />
    <x:col min="3" max="3" width="12.77734375" customWidth="1" />
  </x:cols>
```

MS Word:

```
<w:tblGrid>
      <w:gridCol w:w="454" />
      <w:gridCol w:w="1100" />
      <w:gridCol w:w="1380" />
</w:tblGrid>
```

Can someone help me or guide me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2):

Word's column widths are stored as twentieths of a point. You might find this article instructive http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableGrid.php.

Excel does not use a measurement unit, so a 1:1 conversion will be difficult, at best. Excel's width depends on the font size used; Word's will not (unless the table properties are set to expand to fit content).

From `width (Column Width)` at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column?view=openxml-2.8.1

> Column width measured as the number of characters of the maximum digit
>   width of the numbers 0, 1, 2, …, 9 as rendered in the normal style's
>   font. There are 4 pixels of margin padding (two on each side), plus 1
>   pixel padding for the gridlines.
>
> width = Truncate([{Number of Characters} * {Maximum Digit Width} + {5
>   pixel padding}]/{Maximum Digit Width}*256)/256
>
> [Example: Using the Calibri font as an example, the maximum digit
>   width of 11 point font size is 7 pixels (at 96 dpi). In fact, each
>   digit is the same width for this font. Therefore, if the cell width is
>   8 characters wide, the value of this attribute must be
>   Truncate([8*7+5]/7*256)/256 = 8.7109375. end example]
>
> To translate the value of width in the file into the column width
>   value at runtime (expressed in terms of pixels), use this calculation:
>
> =Truncate(((256 * {width} + Truncate(128/{Maximum Digit
>   Width}))/256)*{Maximum Digit Width})
>
> [Example: Using the same example as above, the calculation would be
>   Truncate(((256*8.7109375+Truncate(128/7))/256)*7) = 61 pixels. end
>   example]
>
> To translate from pixels to character width, use this calculation:
>
> =Truncate(({pixels}-5)/{Maximum Digit Width} * 100+0.5)/100
>
> [Example: Using the example above, the calculation would be
>   Truncate((61-5)/7*100+0.5)/100 = 8 characters. end example]
>
> [Note: when wide borders are applied, part of the left/right border
>   must overlap with the 2 pixel padding on each side. Wide borders do
>   not affect the width calculation of the column. end note]
>
> [Note: When the sheet is in the mode to view formulas instead of
>   values, the pixel width of the column is doubled. end note]
>
> The possible values for this attribute are defined by the W3C XML
>   Schema double datatype.

The following might also be helpful http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/01/18/calculating-column-widths-in-excel-open-xml/, which provides code for doing the calculation in the first equation, above.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It wasn't the answer I was looking for. I am fully aware of how either programs Word or Excel calculate the widths.

If it was easy, I wouldn't have asked! :)   MS shows it can be done "on the fly" by copy/pasting as I suggested / wrote in my question.

Comment: @Prholm Then your question is not clearly formulated at all.

Comment: I wrote: "
I am looking for a formula which can convert Excel columns width to Word table width". seems pretty clear to me.. 

I provide a small example on how to produce the result (Excel copy -> Word paste and save bot files and examine them, giving the listed coed result for xlsx and docs file snippets in the post). 

SInce MS can "convert" the tables on the fly I was wondering how it could be done! If it ain't a formula then it might call an Excel function providing / giving the correct result..

Comment: @PrHolm Unclear: Which programming language this should be in? Using the Interop or Open XML? Etc, etc.

Comment: No specifik programming language I need the formular (in math terms) like the one you provide in your first answer  .. 

If you would provide any programming examples in your answer then C# using OpenXml would be fine.